# To get IP address of Cisco UCS emulator running on VMware

Tags: java, eclipse, vmware, cisco

I am running a Cisco UCS emulator on VMware workstation 
to go with my project I need to get a IP address of this UCS emulator through Eclipse by using Java code. 
i have tried

```
public class Ipadd
{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        InetAddress inetAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        byte[] addr = inetAddr.getAddress();
        // Convert to dot representation
        String ipAddr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < addr.length; i++) {

            if (i > 0) {
                ipAddr += ".";

            }
            ipAddr += addr[i] & 0xFF;
       }

       System.out.println("IP Address: " + ipAddr);

    }
}
```

I am getting IP address of VMware but I want get IP address of emulator

can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Start the UCS Emulator in VM, use username: config password: config.
Once you login, the UCS will display the HTTP page to use the UCS Manager, the HTTP Page is displayed as the the IP Address of the UCS.